# Excel formula weekdays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a formula that will give me the expected due date of a task (15 business days), and that needs to exclude weekends, that its easy and I did it with a simple weekday formula:

=IF(WEEKDAY(G8)=1,G8+19,IF(WEEKDAY(G8)=2,G8+18,G8+20))

G8 = Start date;

The tricky question is that I want the start date on Monday every time a task starts during the weekend.

Ex:
I started a task on Saturday, so the start date will be on Monday 00:00.

Comment: Why not just use the `WORKDAY` function?

Comment: With workday i believe it will happen the same, if the request come on weekend will start at that time and not next Monday at 00:00, what is missing in the formula is something that will start counting on Monday 00:00 and not Monday 5:00pm for example.

Comment: Depending on what you want, it is easily compensated for, usually by adding or subtracting one from the date, and then adjusting the number of days to add.

Comment: Post an example of where the WORKDAY function is providing an undesired result, and what you would like the result to be.

Answer (score 0):

You state you want the start date to be Monday if the actual date is Saturday or Sunday.  And I will assume that you also want the start date to be Monday if the actual date is Monday.

That being the case, the following formula should work (for 15 days):

```
=WORKDAY(WORKDAY(G8,-1),16)
```

Don't forget you can optionally add a range of holiday dates to this function.

We subtract one workday from the actual start date, then increase the number of workdays to add by one.  And this adjusts for the weekends the way you state you want.